# How to loop element in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 3 fields:

```
<input type="datetime" name="input-data" id="datetime-start">
<input type="datetime" name="input-data" id="datetime-end">
<input type="text" name="input-data" id="text-basic">
```

And i need to check if there is something entered, so i firsly did it like `jQuery.each('[name="input-data"]', function()` and used `this` in loop, but get some errors. After small debug i found a way like `jQuery.each(jQuery('[name="input-data"]'), function(key, value)`, but when i trying to do `console.log(value.val());` i get en error. So i decided to look what is in `value` and was surprised - there was just a string `<input type="datetime" name="input-data" id="datetime-start">`. So how can i loop trough all input values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on a jQuery instance, e.g.:

```
jQuery('[name="input-data"]').each(function() {
    // Here, `this` is the DOM element. If you want to use jQuery methods,
    // wrap the element in a jQuery instance:
    var input = jQuery(this);

    // Now, input.val() will give you the value
});
```

jQuery's API is sometimes a bit confusing. This is one of those times. jQuery has two similar but different functions: The `each` you call on jQuery instances (see above), and [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which you can use to loop through arrays, objects, and array-like objects.

Your code using `jQuery.each(jQuery('[name="input-data"]', function...` does work, because jQuery instances are array-like, but then within the function you weren't wrapping the DOM element, which is why `val()` didn't work. But the above is the normal way to loop through a set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[name="input-data"]').each(function(el){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X6vhg/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).val());
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.each()` incorrectly. Try this:

```
jQuery('[name="input-data"]').each(function() {
    // Use $(this) to access current object
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you're working on HTML5, aren't you? why don't you use the given validation of html5?
Just set attribute "required='true'" and you should be done ;-)

there is also a good way to do this in jquery mobile. if i remember it correctly, you have to set the class 'required' to the wanted input attributes. For reference:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/30/Example-of-form-validation-in-a-jQuery-Mobile-Application

Comment: ...because your function will fail, when js is switched off. HTML5 Form validation is native and working fine.

Comment: Mobile Safari for example doesn't validate forms. Even the desktop version isn't doing it.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: No, just load the right js and it will compense all disadvantages of safari's lack of validation. I did many projects like this, and it definitely definitely possible.